# How can I verify email IDs through terminal commands?

Tags: networking, server, email

I'm trying to verify email ids through terminal, but it said it can't find the server nxdomain.

I used the following commands

```
nslookup -type=mx <mailid>
nslookup -q=mx <mailid>
```

But it shows only ip address and can't find server nxdomain.

Kindly give the possible solutions.

Comment: This domain may not have a mail server. For example, `askubuntu.com` does not a mail server.

Comment: I checked valid domain also, such as google, linkedin and etc...

Comment: `nslookup -type=mx google.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
google.com      mail exchanger = 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com      mail exchanger = 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com      mail exchanger = 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com      mail exchanger = 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com      mail exchanger = 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.`  Please, add your sample output in your question too.

Comment: i tried, it shows following only:administrator@VSPLBNG-NAVEENRAJR:~$ nslookup -type=mx www.naveen10204@gmail.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find www.naveen10204\@gmail.com: NXDOMAIN

Comment: You should not use e-mail addresses in `nslookup` command. Only host names or domain names.